# exe Appcrash on giving a specific folder path and specific exe name

Tags: migration, exe, powerbuilder, crash

I am working in a Powerbuilder application.
I migrated the application from 11.0 to 12.6 and deployed the application. I also generated dlls for Powerbuilder 12.6 version from install run time packager msi file. When I place the exe(say exe name as "vm.exe") and dlls in a folder path(say C:\abcd\vm and run the application,the app crashes. But if I copy the same exe and paste in same folder by changing the exe name as vmcopy.exe, it works. Only with specific exe name, it crashes. Also if I place the same dlls and exe in some other folder path(say C:\abcd\vmtest) name it works fine with exe name as "vm.exe". So only for a specific folder path and specific exe name the app crashes.I want the application to work with the specific exe name and specific folder location. Please help me on solving this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What info do you get from the crash? A specific error message, or a generic message from windows? Also, is your specific path a system protected one like `c:\windows`?

Comment: No it is not system protected.
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH

Application Name: vmi.exe
Application Version: 1.0.0.1
Application Timestamp:53bcb59b
Fault Module Name: PBVM126.dll
Fault Module Version: 12.6.0.3506
Fault ModuleTimestamp: 53bcb5a0
Execution Code:80000003

Comment: Have you tried using ADplus (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350) to catch the reamining failures? This may give us more clues to the failure(s).